# Can a PostgreSQL database partition be re-attached after it has been detached?

Tags: postgresql, partitioning

Is it possible to re-attach a partition in PostgreSQL once it has been detached?

```
ALTER TABLE measurement DETACH PARTITION measurement_y2006m02;
ALTER TABLE measurement ATTACH PARTITION measurement_y2006m02;
```

If not, would the best route be to re-add the records back to the original table and recreate the partition?

```
INSERT INTO measurement SELECT * FROM measurement_y2006m02;
DROP TABLE measurement_y2006m02;
ALTER TABLE measurement ATTACH PARTITION measurement_y2006m02
    FOR VALUES FROM ('2006-02-01') TO ('2006-03-01' );
```

Comment: You apparently know about `attach partition` - so what exactly is your question?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name after measurement_y2006m02 is detached it just becomes a table like any other with no connection to the parent table. `attach partition` seems to create a partition and I would expect it to be able to attach measurement_y2006m02 since it is an existing table. Maybe it does though. If not, I believe another option would be `ALTER TABLE measurement_y2006m02 INHERIT measurement`. That might be a mess though to have some partitions and some inheritance. I plan to create test cases for both today.

Comment: No. `attach partition` does not "create" a new table. It only registered that tables as partition of the `measurement` table.  It doesn't touch the data anywhere. Why don't you just try it?

Answer (score 2):

Yes It can be done.

But while attaching it follows different syntax.

```
ALTER TABLE measurement DETACH PARTITION measurement_y2006m02;
ALTER TABLE measurement ATTACH PARTITION measurement_y2006m02 
  FOR VALUES FROM ('2006-02-01') TO ('2006-03-01' );
```

Note: We also need to keep it locks that will be created while attaching and Detaching.

As per documentation,
Attaching a partition acquires a SHARE UPDATE EXCLUSIVE lock on the parent table, in addition to the ACCESS EXCLUSIVE locks on the table being attached and on the default partition (if any).

While Detaching we can use CONCURRENTLY option to reduce the locking